# Powershell Get-ADGroup : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read line by line of a text file into the get-adgroup cmdlet to get a list of which users are a member of the groups from a txt file

```
Clear-Host;
$groups = "./desktop/groups.txt"
$arrayofgroups = Get-Content $groups 

foreach ($item in $arrayofgroups) {
    Get-ADGroup $item -properties * | select samaccountname, members
}
```

The text file looks like this:

```
"group 1"
"group 2"
```

The below code returns:

> Get-ADGroup : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity' to the target. Exception setting "Identity": "Cannot validate argument on parameter: 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not
>    null or empty and then try the command again."
>   At line:6 char:15
>   +   {get-adgroup <<<<  $item -properties * | select samaccountname, members}
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

However, when I loop through the array, it returns to the group name ok

```
Clear-Host;
$groups = "./desktop/groups.txt"
$arrayofgroups = Get-Content $groups 

foreach ($item in $arrayofgroups ) {
    $item
}
```

I have verfied that if you simply run the below it works fine.

```
get-adgroup "group 1" -properties * | select samaccountname, members
```

I'm new to PowerShell from VBscript, and am not sure why this doesn't work, any thoughts?

Comment: What does $arrayofgroups.count return?  If those names are quoted in the file, you should remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a PSBreakpoint on the line containing the `Get-ADGroup` command, within the `foreach` loop. In the debugger, type `$Item` to examine the value of the `$Item` variable. Also try typing `$Item.Length` to see how many characters long it is exactly. Make sure that your source text file doesn't have any extra, unnecessary whitespace in it.

Comment: Excellent Idea, the variable was  '"group 1"' I removed the double quotes from the text file and it processed normally